# return value on a merge query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using a merge query in my stored procedure.  I would like to return a flag when the Insert is fired. i.e. when the PK does not match.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[IUD_QtrMinute] 

    @qtrminlat varchar(5),
    @qtrminlng varchar(6),
    @callCenter varchar(20),
    @areaId int

AS
BEGIN
    merge [dbo].[map_qtrmin] as target
    using (values(@qtrminlat, @qtrminlng, @areaId,  @callCenter))
        as source ([qtrmin_lat],  [qtrmin_long], [area_id], [call_center])
        on (target.qtrmin_lat = @qtrminlat) and (target.qtrmin_long = @qtrminlng)
    when  matched and @areaId = 0
        then delete
    when matched then
            update
            set [area_id] = @areaId 
    when not matched then --return a bit flag or something  
    insert([qtrmin_lat],  [qtrmin_long], [area_id], [long_length], [call_center])
    values(source.qtrmin_lat,  source.qtrmin_long, source.area_id, 1, source.call_center);

END
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Read about the [output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `output` clause, here is a small example:

```
select 1 a, 1 b into #t0
union all select 2, 2
union all select 3, 3

select 1 a, 1 b into #t1
union all select 2, 2
union all select 4, 4

declare @t table (a int, b int);
merge
  #t0 t0
using
  #t1 t1 on t0.a = t1.a
when matched then
  update set t0.b = t0.b
output
  inserted.a, inserted.b
into
  @t (a, b)
;

select * from @t;
```

Table @t will contain matched values. You can use it to set your flag variable,

```
if exists(select * from @t) begin
 -- ..
end;
```